# How to validate a sequence of items from .NET Core configuration using IOptions etc

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, configuration, .net-standard-2.0

I have trouble finding a way to validate items in a sequence for .NET Core configuration (tried with .NET 5 and 3.1).

Say that my settings are like so:

```
{
"MyOpt": {
    "IntOpt": 5,
    "StrOpt": "...",
    "Inner": {
        "InnerStr": "...",
        "InnerInt": 7
    },
    "Inners": [
        {
            "InnerStr": "...",
            "InnerInt": 1
        },
        {
            "InnerStr": "...",
            "InnerInt": 2
        }
    ]
}
}


public class Inner
{
    public string InnerStr { get; set; }

    [Range(0, 1000, ErrorMessage = "Value {0} must be between {1} and {2}")]
    public int InnerInt { get; set; }
}

public class MyOpt
{
    [Range(0, 1000, ErrorMessage = "Value {0} must be between {1} and {2}")]
    public int IntOpt { get; set; }
    public string StrOpt { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Inner> Inners { get; set; }
}
```

And that I configure this in my Startup.cs like so:

```
services
  .AddOptions<MyOpt>()
  .Bind(Configuration.GetSection("MyOpt"))
  .ValidateDataAnnotations();
```

When I try to access this from, say in a controller in a WebAPI:

```
    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IOptions<OptOpt> options)
    {
        var whatever = options.Value.IntOpt;
        _logger = logger;
    }
```

Validations kick in correctly for MyOpt.IntOpt or MyOpt.Inner.InnerInt (both data annotations and conversion errors cause an exception to be thrown, e.g. for

```
{
"MyOpt": {
    "IntOpt": "abc",
    ...
}
```

I get a nice

```
ArgumentException: abc is not a valid value for Int32. (Parameter 'value').
```

**However**, if one of `MyOpt.Inners` items is misconfigured, it is silently dropped, e.g. for

```
{
"MyOpt": {
    // ...
    "Inners": [
        {
            "InnerStr": "...",
            "InnerInt": 1
        },
        {
            "InnerStr": "...",
            "InnerInt": "abc"
        }
    ]
}
}
```

I only get one item in MyOpt.Inners (the first one) and I can't seem to find a way for this to somehow "participate" in the validation - or that the binding failure of "abc" is reported through an exception.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Validation attributes won't by default go inside collections and validate their content, that's why attributes on the elements in your collection are not called.

You could implement `IValidatableObject` and trigger the validation of items in your collection:

```
 public class MyOpt : IValidatableObject
    {
        [Range(0, 1000, ErrorMessage = "Value {0} must be between {1} and {2}")]
        public int IntOpt { get; set; }
        public string StrOpt { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Inner> Inners { get; set; }
    
        public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext){
          var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
          foreach (var item in this.Inners){
          var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
               if (!Validator.TryValidateObject(item, new ValidationContext(item, validationContextItems), validationResults, true)))
    {
results.AddRange(validationResults);
}

          }
        }

return result;
    }
```

Note: code is untested, just a quick suggestion, look for docu on`IValidatableObject` and `Validator`.

Comment: OK, thanks for that. Yeah, I tried a variation of this, with `services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IValidateOptions<MyOpt>, MyOptValidator>());` - which works, but looked too manual. I also tried `AddOptions<Inner>()`, but that didn't seem to do anything either :-(